# Oracle SQL syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: Table]

This is my table structure . I have many problems in trying to make different things work .

1. How do I enter the values into task where Monday = 62 ?

   ```
   INSERT INTO it_time_track (task,percentage)
   VALUES ('Support',null) where Monday=62; commit ;
   ```

**This gives me an error**

-- I fixed it by making it an interactive Grid on Oracle Apex and doing a select to display this table and then I went on to edit it manually .

Comment: You probably want `UPDATE` not `INSERT`. Also looks like you have two very different and unrelated questions. Feel free to separate those, we don't charge anything extra.

Comment: `INSERT` creates a new record. You already have a row where `Monday = 62` so you want to `UPDATE` it. Also... This table looks like someone is mistaking their database table for an excel spreadsheet, which is almost definitely leading you to "have many problems in trying to make different things work ."

Comment: Instead the structure of this table should be `id | percentage | day_of_week | value` your `daily total` would be derived through SQL, not stored on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE it_time_track 
SET Monday = (SELECT SUM(Monday)  
                  FROM it_time_track 
                  ) 
WHERE Id = 7
```

Comment: [Code: 934, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Comment: Why is there a `sum()` in there?

Comment: Because we want to sum the values in the column Monday

Comment: How would I derive the daily total from SQL

Comment: My bad. I forgot about the aggregate limitations. You want the SUM of Monday to show up in Id 7, correct? I've updated my answer.

Comment: [Code: 1427, SQL State: 21000]  ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Yes I think you understood what I want to do .

Comment: When I do select sum(monday) from it_time_track , it gives me the right answer .

Comment: Wait. How can my subquery return more than one row???  That's not possible with an aggregate with no WHERE clause. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want. I thought you only wanted Monday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177599/discussion-between-naq-23-and-keith-harris).